# how can I use redirect_to :controller => "posts", :action => "index" in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and I have used

> redirect_to :controller => "posts", :action => "index"

in controller and now I can use this in my views. When using it in views it shows

> **NoMethodError in Home#index**
>
> Showing
>   /Users/#####/RubyProjects/devise_example/app/views/home/index.html.erb
>   where line #9 raised:
>
> undefined method `redirect_to'

How can I get the index of post from home index?

Comment: why don't you just add <%= link_to(controller: "posts", action: "index"); %> #?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3170475/567863)

Comment: `render` is controller's method and unless the method is made available as helper it is not accessible in view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want to redirect in your view ? The redirection has to be done in the controller.

If you want to make a link to posts#index use this `<%= link_to "Posts", posts_path %>`

Comment: `render` is used show the view directly, you don't pass (again) in the controller action. `redirect`pass through controller action before showing the view

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a redirect in a view does make sense. If you want to do so, all you need to do is change your method call to `controller.redirect_to` since the `redirect_to` method only exists under the controller.

Example: `<% controller.redirect_to posts_path %>`

---

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30908769