# How to play songs from database one by one in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a database which consists of songs.
what i want to do is, fetch songs one by one from database and play them.

I have used below code buts its not working for me

```
<% @playlists.each do |playlist| %>
  <%= audio_tag(playlist.song.url, controls: true, autoplay: true ) %><br>
  <% redirect_to playlists_path %>
<% end %>
```

Its giving me the error

```
undefined mehtod redirect_to
```

I know its not the best method to do this, but I am just trying my options.
How to do this in easy way.

Comment: The best way to tackle this is a JavaScript-based audio player and a list of media files to play.

Comment: @tadman can u please provide some source for this.

Comment: @ChandraShekhar Stack Overflow is not a place for software recommendations.  The words in tadman's comments should be enough for you to start googling and trying things you find.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I use redirect\_to :controller => "posts", :action => "index" in views?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276487/how-can-i-use-redirect-to-controller-posts-action-index-in-views)

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3170494/2483138), `redirect_to` is not a method you can use in the rails view layer.  Thus, it's an undefined method when you try to use it the way you're trying to.

You might want to look at `link_to` if the user is supposed to click something.  If you want it to happen automatically, however, I don't think there's a canonical solution, so you'd do well to follow advice from the comments and use a javascript music player library.